# How can I use RegEx with React Router?

Tags: regex, reactjs

I am working on React project and I ran into an issue.
Basically my app uses a dashboard view on most paths except on those paths:
- / (root directory) which displays the HomePage component
- /signin which displays the SignIn component
- /signup which displays the SignUp component
- /pwdrecovery which displays the PasswordRecovery component

I want to direct those routes using a regular expression but so far I've only been able to make it work with the root directory.

Here is my current code:

```
 render() {
return (
  <div>
    <ScrollToTop>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact />
        <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
      </Switch>
      <Route
        path="/(.+)"
        render={() => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <ResponsiveMenu />
            <Header />
            <SidePanel profile={profile} />
            <HamburgerMenu />
            <div className="container-dashboard">
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                <Route path="/log" component={LogDashboard} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      />
    </ScrollToTop>
  </div>
);
```

My question is: Can I achieve this with regular expression? If so what regular expression do I need to use (I suck with RegEx) ?

And if not, how can I make this work ? Should I create a component (WithDashboard) that takes another component as props and renders the component inside the dashboard div along with the header and sidepanel ? Or should I use the withRouter() higher order component and use the props.location.pathname ?

Comment: Seems you are trying to redirect every other route at the same destination. Why don't simply use `path="*"` ?

Comment: If I do this, every route is going to lead to the Fragment containing the dashboard.